# Excel nesting error

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I'm using Excel 2013 and I have had to create a If statement which basically chooses a student's grade depending on a certain mark number (obviously, nesting is needed) Here is the If statement I created:

```
=IF(E2<=20,"N",
IF(OR(E2>=21,E2<=25),4,
    IF(OR(E2>=26,E2<=32),"5C",
        IF(OR(E2>=33,E2<=38),"5B", 
            IF(OR(E2>=39, E2<=44), "5A", 
                IF(OR(E2>=45, E2<=53), "6C", 
                    IF(OR(E2>=54, E2<=61), "6B", 
                        IF(OR(E2>=62, E2<=71), "6A", 
                            IF(OR(E2>=72, E2<=87), "7C", 
                                IF(OR(E2>=88, E2<=103), "7B", 
                                    IF(OR(E2>=104, E2<=120), "7A")))))))))))
```

The error I receive is:

> the specified formula cannot be entered because it uses more levels of nesting than allowed in the current file format

My question is, how do I shorten this statement to allow Excel to use it?

Comment: I recommend using the solution proposed by suspectus.....but Excel 2013 will allow at least 64 levels of nesting, so if you are having problems with that it probably means you have saved the file as 2003 compatible - just save as an xlsx file - then shut workbook and re-open - and 64 levels will be allowed (although you need AND rather than OR as Sakir says)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the logic in the spreadsheet cells. One column for the minimum score, and one column for the grade-:

```
       A     B 
1      0     N
2      21    4
3      26    5C
4      33    5B
5      39    5A
6      45    6C
7      54    6B
8      72    7C
9      88    7B
10    104    7A
```

Then do a `vlookup` to get the grade from the actual score. vlookup will find the highest value in the A column that is less that the lookup value of 38.

In the example vlookup below 38 is the score, A1:B10 is the lookup table  2 is the 2nd column (in this case the B column) that contains the result (the grade).

```
=VLOOKUP(38, A1:B3, 2, TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following formula.

```
=LOOKUP(E2;{0;21;26;33;39;45;54;62;72;88;104;121};{"N";4;"5C";"5B";"5A";"6C";"6B";"6A";"7C";"7B";"7C";"No match"})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different solutions. `AND` agreements using `OR` instead of the first that comes to mind.

```
=IF(E2<=20,"N",
IF(AND(E2>=21,E2<=25),4,
    IF(AND(E2>=26,E2<=32),"5C", ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way, in my opinion, is to write a UDF. Then you can use VBA and a CASE statement.
Experiment with this code in VBA to create a UDF named GRADE() - just type it into a MODULE in the VBE:

```
Function Grade(Marks)
 Dim Score As Integer
 Score = Marks * 1
 Select Case Score
    Case 1 To 20
        Grade = "N"
    Case 21 To 50
        Grade = "C"
    Case 51 To 90
        Grade = "B"
    Case 91 To 120
        Grade = "A"
 End Select
End Function
```

Then use the Function GRADE() as you would any other function but type the address of the argument - like this GRADE(B7) to use it

Answer (score -1):

```
=+IF(O3="Negative","Negative",IF(P3="Negative","Negative",IF(Q3="Negative","Negative",IF(R3="Negative","Negative",IF(O3="Refer","Refer",IF(P3="Refer","Refer",IF(Q3="Refer","Refer",IF(R3="Refer","Refer","Positive"))))))))
```

I find the final status in 4 cells have positive,negative,refer,pending or blank